# Can't connect to the Internet because of "no network interface"

Tags: networking, kubuntu

I have installed Kubuntu 11.04 in my laptop. This morning when I powered it on and tried to connect to the Internet, I can't because of "no network interface" error. How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Which NIC does your laptop has? and `ifconfig` output please

Answer (score 0):

You must first reconfigure network interfaces:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up

sudo ifconfig
```

You must see:

```
eth0Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:11:5b:91:25:3e
inet addr:xxx.xxx.xx.xx Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Mask:255.255.0.0
inet6 addr: fe80::211:5bff:fe91:253e/64 Диапазон:Ссылка
ВВЕРХ BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:648009 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1075413 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
```

Then install `pppoeconf` utility (`sudo apt-get install pppoeconf`) to connect to the internet.
After installing `pppoeconf`, run `sudo ppoeconf`
and use this utility to check your network drivers. You must choose the interface (eth0 or eth1) to connect to your dsl-modem, login and then enter password.